# Calling custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

need some help with cpt having next-previous links with title or related posts. I'm using Oceanwp theme. For normal posts it show related posts. But for CPT, some code has to be edited.

In the child theme I've copied some files and I can see related posts in cpt but with default categories not with custom taxonomy associated with CPT.  This is the code in theme i need help with:

```
    // Term
$term_tax = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_single_post_next_prev_taxonomy', 'post_tag' );
$term_tax = $term_tax ? $term_tax : 'post_tag';
```

It is in my child theme next-prev-subjects.php and related-posts-subjects.php.

How can I edit this code to use custom taxonomies. I've CPT named Subjects and 3 category like custom taxonomies: Physics, Chem, Maths and one tags like custom taxonomy named tagsubject.

I tried this one but didn't worked

```
// Term
    $term_tax = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_single_post_next_prev_taxonomy', 'subject_category' );
    $term_tax = $term_tax ? $term_tax : 'subject_category';
```

Do I've to use this:

```
$terms_tax = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => 'physics','chem','maths'
'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Any help with this way or any other way will be really appreciated. For other ways I did found similar questions in this forum but I don't know which files to edit or create in the child theme.

Comment: I think it should be `'taxonomy' => array( 'physics', 'chem', 'maths' ),` for multiple taxonomies with a `,` comma after the first line of arguments. BTW, what `didn't work` means which you might need to elaborate such as sharing `error message` or `result` you have seen.

Comment: i tried this $term_tax = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_single_post_next_prev_taxonomy', array( 'physics', 'chem', 'maths' ); It gave an error message : PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED ';', EXPECTING ',' OR ')' ... /NEXT-PREV-IPCASES.PHP ON LINE 19 . You can take a look at files here https://github.com/gvawake/layout/tree/master .

Comment: That error is because you didn't close `get_theme_mod` properly. You need to add another `)` before your closing `;`. The error is pretty literal in this case.

Comment: the error went after putting another `)` . But still seeing the posts from default category and not custom taxonomies. There's another line in next-prev-cpt.php apart from above two `//Terms Lines`, `'taxonomy'              => $term_tax,` which I changed to `'taxonomy'              => array( 'cr', 'pt', 'tm' ),` Now got this warning ` WARNING: ILLEGAL OFFSET TYPE IN ISSET OR EMPTY IN /APP/PUBLIC/WP-INCLUDES/TAXONOMY.PHP ON LINE 290` .